# How to handle user notifications for same object?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I'm using this code [http://codegains.com/2014/06/laravel-4-notification-system/](https://www.hugedomains.com/domain_profile.cfm?d=codegains&e=com) 
for my notification system, it works OK. But now I've run into problems, users are flooded with notifications.
What I mean is, that if 5 users likes one image, author of that image will get 5 notifications with "User X liked your picture image.png". Where X is 5 different name.
Now I want to know if anyone has idea on how to change so that in above case, user will get only 1 notification saying "Users X,Y,Z liked your picture image.png" .

Edit:
Here's structure of tables "notifications"
[image]
<sub>(source: [codegains.com](http://codegains.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/notifications-2.png))</sub>

Now I'm trying to group notifications with iterating through all notifications that are selected from DB with ORDER BY object_id and I compare current object_id with previous and so I get the right form. But this takes way to much time, because it starts this on every page load (main page). And 1000 users, with 1000 notifications... :\

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to add an index on your `is_read` field so that you can speed your queries up, and then probably use some kind of grouping to get the list of users that have 'posted' a given notification. I don't think this is something Eloquent can do natively, but you should check out the `GROUP_CONCAT` MySQL function, it'll do the `X, Y, Z` grouping you want per type of notification for a given user.

Comment: I don't know exactly how your tables fit together, but something like `SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(user.name) AS user_names FROM notification LEFT JOIN user /* JOIN CONDITION HERE */ WHERE is_read = '0' AND user_id = '/* LOGGED IN USER ID  */' GROUP BY subject` is what I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping with `created_at`.

You will check for `created_at` is within 30 seconds and group the results and fire every notification that is above 30 seconds and otherwise you will group and fire a group.

For example:

```
$oNotifications = Notifications::where('is_read', '=', false)->get();

$aNotifyGroup = [];
foreach($oNotifications as $oNotify)
{
    if($oNotify->created_at->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now()) <= 30)
    {
        // Add to group for later fire
         $aNotifiyGroup[] = $oNotify;
    }
    else
    {
        //Fire notification
    }
}    

//Fire Grouped notification
foreach($aNotifyGroup as $oNotify)
{
    //Fire
}
```